# Missing this on new operator

Tags: javascript, ajax, new-operator

I missing the this on return on AJAX call. I have the

## interar.js

```
interar.Remoter = function (data) {
  this.server = data.server;
  this.init(data);
};

interar.Remoter.prototype.init = function (data) {
    var succeedCB, errorCB, lPayload, promiseCB;
    succeedCB = function (result) {
        // When return the called the this is === window not in.
        this.uuid = result.uuid;
        console.log("UUID v4 From Server " +  this.uuid);
    };
    errorCB = function () {
        console.error("Not Allow to Connect to Server ");
    }
    // This execute a XHTTPRequest Async call
    interar.execute(succeedCB, errorCB, {'w' : data});
};
```

## index.html

```
var W = new interar.Remoter("mydata");
```

At the return of the **succeedCB** the this is ***window*** not **interar** instance

Comment: Sorry, the in is just abbreviation I change, the name. Thanks for the heads ups

Comment: You should construct a `interar.Remote` instead.

Comment: Why does your code sample have `interar.Remoter = ` and `interar.Remote /*no r*/.prototype.init = `?  Is that in your original code?  Why `new interar` instead of `new interar.Remoter`?

Comment: Thanks, for the headups, I make a mistake in the copy/paste to stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be

```
interar.Remote.prototype.init = function (data) {
    var succeedCB, errorCB, lPayload, promiseCB;
    var self = this; <-- Assign this to a variable for closure bases access
    succeedCB = function (result) {
        // When return the called the this is === window not in.
        self.uuid = result.uuid;
        console.log("UUID v4 From Server " +  self.uuid);
    };
    errorCB = function () {
        console.error("Not Allow to Connect to Server ");
    }
    // This execute a XHTTPRequest Async call
    interar.execute(succeedCB, errorCB, {'w' : data});
};
```

When you pass `succeedCB` as a callback, the context from which `succeedCB` executed will not be aware of the `this` instance.

So we can make use of closure to make `this` accessible inside `succeedCB`

Answer (score 1):

Cache `this` on initialisation of the instance:

```
interar.Remoter.prototype.init = function (data) {
    var succeedCB, errorCB, lPayload, promiseCB, self = this;
    succeedCB = function (result) {
        // When return the called the this is === window not in.
        self.uuid = result.uuid;
        console.log("UUID v4 From Server " +  self.uuid);
    };
    errorCB = function () {
        console.error("Not Allow to Connect to Server ");
    }
    // This execute a XHTTPRequest Async call
    interar.execute(succeedCB, errorCB, {'w' : data});
};
```

Also you probably wanted to set `prototype.init` of `Remoter` instead of `Remote`.